How to run a rule with the working dir being the local storage prefix?
Snakemake 8.20.3
In my configuration, I set
default-storage-provider: fs
local-storage-prefix: /wrk-vakka/users/$USER/local

However, when I run a rule such as
localrules: test_lf
rule test_lf:
    output: "touched_file.txt"
    shell:  """
        echo $(pwd)
        touch touched_file.txt
    """

Then it creates touched_file.txt in the directory where my Snakefile is, and not under the specified local-storage-prefix.
How can I make a shell rule that uses the local-storage-prefix as the working directory for its shell script?

The solution was to use the output wildcard inside the script as follows:
localrules: test_lf
rule test_lf:
    output: "touched_file.txt"
    shell:  """
        echo $(pwd)
        touch {output}
    """


Two things. That is not a wildcard you show following touch. And second this isn't the simply the solution to your issue, this is how you'd normally use what you set in output and input directives within your shell commands as part of a shell directive.   Nice example in the documentation here: "bwa mem {input} | samtools view -Sb - > {output}". If in the output directive, they were named things, like fn = "touched_file.txt", it would be touch {output.fn} in your shell directive script.
